# Emgucv CornerSubPix() throwing OpenCV: count >= 0

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv, camera-calibration

Hi I'm trying the chessboard calibration since a while. Everything is looking good. The edges are detected very well and the lines get drawn on my chessboard as well. The issue comes when I try to calculate the error. To be specific after/when I call the `CornerSubPix()`funktion.

Thats how I call the method:

```
CvInvoke.CornerSubPix(_GrayFrame, _CornersPointsVec[k], new Size(11, 11), new Size(-1, -1), new MCvTermCriteria(30, 0.1));
```

where `_GrayFrame` is `Emgu.CV.Mat` which is the "image" I'm using.

`_CornersPointsVec` is `Emgu.CV.Util.VectorOfPointF`

Throwing the following exeption:

```
Emgu.CV.Util.CvException: OpenCV: count >= 0
   at Emgu.CV.CvInvoke.CvErrorHandler(Int32 status, IntPtr funcName, IntPtr errMsg, IntPtr fileName, Int32 line, IntPtr userData)
   at Emgu.CV.CvInvoke.cveCornerSubPix(IntPtr image, IntPtr corners, Size& win, Size& zeroZone, MCvTermCriteria& criteria)
   at Emgu.CV.CvInvoke.CornerSubPix(IInputArray image, IInputOutputArray corners, Size win, Size zeroZone, MCvTermCriteria criteria)
```

obviously this exeption is not very helpful in therms what could be wrong. So I hope someone can give me at last an hint ...